# Prometheus Endpoint Not Working Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 Spring Webflux enabled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-webflux

I followed the documentation here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints) and made sure application.yml file has the below

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      expose:
        health, info, httptrace, metrics, threaddump, mappings, prometheus
```

As per the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/actuator-api/html/#prometheus) the following doesn't work.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus' -i
```

I get 404 Handler mapping not found exception. Can someone please let me know how to enable prometheus endpoint for scraping purposes and what URL endpoint I need to use to test it out?

```
o.s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[276] - Did not find handler method for [/actuator/prometheus]
```

All other endpoints health, info, httptrace, threaddump, mappings are working perfectly fine.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A bit late - but just for the record - I can verify that this works now in 2.0.0.RELEASE.

Dependencies (gradle):

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus')
```

application.yaml ([reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints))

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info,prometheus
```

I also tested with RC1 - the prometheus endpoint does not show up for some reason - just as @ROCKY explained.

Answer (score 13):

There's some things you could check:

1. Have you added the necessary `MeterRegistry` implementation so that the Prometheus "subsystem" of the `Micrometer` instrumentation library is present? (The [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io) library is powering the Actuator implementation as of Spring Boot 2.0)

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
       <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Without a specific `MeterRegistry` implementation you just end up with the regular `/actuator/metrics` endpoint powered by the `SimpleMeterRegistry` implementation.
2. Have you actually placed the mentioned properties in a `application.[yml,yaml]` file instead of `application.properties`? (I just stumbled upon the same with a fresh demo project generated with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/).)

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem and managed to fix it by adding "include" tag into the configuration:

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: prometheus,info,metrics,threaddump
```

Answer (score 3):

spring boot does not expose prometheus endpoint by default even if you have `>micrometer-registry-prometheus` in you classpath.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

you need to explicit tell spring boot to expose prometheus endpoint by below property.

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,metrics,prometheus`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem when I upgraded my application from 1.5 to 2.1.3. Was able to fix it by following this [Spring Boot 2.0 Prometheus Backward Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570812/spring-boot-2-0-prometheus-backward-compatibility?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

You need `micrometer-registry-prometheus` in your dependency list and add below to your SpringBootApplication class

```
@Bean
public CollectorRegistry collectorRegistry() {
    return CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry;
}
```