# Spring Boot 2.0 Prometheus Backward Compatibility

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am migrating to Spring Boot 2.0 and I am having issues with my Prometheus Metrics.

I know that MicroMeter is the new way of doing stuff, which is not as crisp as the Prometheus libs but OK.

My issue is that If I do not want to change my metrics now I cannot upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0. Am I right?

I tried the following:

**Trial no 1**

- Keep my implementations "as is"
- add the new dependency `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.0.2` to my app (actuator is already in there)
- change stuff in `application.properties` to get access to the endpoint `actuator/prometheus`

=> My `Counters` and `Gauges` from the past got ignored. OK I understand that from a technical point of view.

**Trial no 2**

- Keep my implementations "as is"
- add the "old" 'io.prometheus' dependencies and remove the micrometer dependency
- change stuff in `application.properties` to get access to the endpoint `actuator/prometheus`

=> Now I get the following excpetion

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

---

So my question is: Is there a "soft migration" way which works?

Answer (score 6):

To make *Trial no 1* work, just add in the Prometheus default registry as a bean that Micrometer will be able to leverage.

```
@Bean
public CollectorRegistry collectorRegistry() {
    return CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry;
}
```

Micrometer doesn't use the default registry by default since it doesn't allow un-registering of meters and can make unit testing quite difficult.

To make *Trial no 2* work will require re-implementing the prometheus actuator endpoint, since that class changed drastically with SpringBoot 2. I wouldn't recommend that approach.

Answer (score 0):

It took me very long to figure out the real problem, rather I had to debug Spring code to solve this. Here is the solution, you need to exclude "micrometer-core" from "spring-boot-starter-actuator" and add "micrometer-registry-prometheus" specifically, like below:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer isn't giving any background so I couldn't figure out why it wasn't helping me. In fact, dropping micrometer-core gave me exceptions during Spring context initialization (it couldn't create prometheusConfig).