# Spring Boot 2.2.2 - Prometheus not working in Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I've upgraded my Spring Boot application to the latest 2.2.2 Boot version. Since then, I only have a metrics endpoint but no Prometheus.

My ***build.gradle.kts*** file has `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator` as dependency, I also added `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus` as the reference suggests ([Prometheus endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints)).

My ***application.yml*** looks like the following:

```
management:
  server:
    port: 9000
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health, shutdown, prometheus
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
```

Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Edit: It was working in Spring Boot 2.2.0. This is the link to download an identical project: [link](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=kotlin&platformVersion=2.2.2.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=webflux,actuator)

Edit 2: I can verify that it works with 2.2.1 as well.

Comment: Hmmm that is weird. I have same set-up and it works just fine.

Comment: @jirka.pinkas are you sure? I just downloaded a new project again and the same result: https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=kotlin&platformVersion=2.2.2.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=webflux,actuator

And add `implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")`

Comment: Just two differences: 1. I use Maven, 2. I have in my application.properties: management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* My dependencies: actuator & micrometer-registry-prometheus & spring-boot-starter-web. EDIT: Just tested it with new project (created on start.spring.io) and it works. EDIT2: Even with management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, shutdown, prometheus it works

Comment: Maybe found your issue: you use webflux, not web.It seems that it doesn't work with webflux (yet): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603285/prometheus-endpoint-not-working-spring-boot-2-0-0-rc1-spring-webflux-enabled?rq=1

Comment: @jirka.pinkas It should be working, I've been using it with WebFlux + Spring Boot 2.2.0 without any problems. :(

Comment: I don't use this bleeding edge technology (webflux), yet :-)

Comment: Try starting your app with `--debug`. It will output a condition evaluation report which may help to explain why the Prometheus endpoint is missing.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson according to the debug logs, it finds the prometheusMeterRegistry bean, the autoconfiguration kicks in, prometheusEndpoint is matched. Is it working for you with the same setup?

Comment: @OCPi Yes, the same setup works fine for me using Spring Boot 2.2.2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I followed your setup, I created a project from [this project loaded](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=kotlin&platformVersion=2.2.2.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=webflux,actuator) **Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE**, I added the following dependency for `Prometheus`

```
implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
```

Also I added the following configuration in `application.yml`

```
management:
  server:
    port: 9000
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health, shutdown, prometheus
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
```

When the application starts you will see the following info which shows you that 3 endpoints are exposed  ***(health, shutdown and prometheus)***.

```
2020-01-05 23:48:19.489  INFO 7700 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 3 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

And used `Postman` for method `GET` this endpoint `http://localhost:9000/actuator/prometheus` and it works well. I created a repository by following these steps [here](https://github.com/jjohxx/demo) So please let me know what error is displayed, or what happens when you don't get the expected result so that I can help and edit this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Then it's something on my side apparently.

Comment: Hi Jonathan.  I make the same steps with sprint boot 2.2.6 but im getting the following: 

2020-04-14 15:28:02.159  INFO 81411 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'

do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @ShalomBalulu also you have `include: health, shutdown, prometheus` right? please open a new question with versions of what you are referring, so I can help you...

Comment: Adding the dependency on io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus did the trick for me. This was not obvious for me when reading the Spring Boot documentation.

Comment: @MichaelChristensen nice, if you have any question related to Spring Boot, you can follow my profile then send an mail, kind regards.

Answer (score 7):

Add below maven dependency for prometheus

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

In application.yml, add the below configuration

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-components: always
      show-details: always
      probes:
        enabled: true
```

Now you could see the below message when you restart the server

```
Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

Access the prometheus url: `http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus`

Comment: SB3, and this is still the relevant dependency that I needed.